# Is there a way to make chunks of mean values of the 2nd dimension of a 3D array while maintaining other dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I am trying to make chunks of mean values of the 2nd dimension of a 3D array using the following code:

```
print(DDD_array.shape)

a = DDD_array
new_DDD = []
for i in range(len(DDD_array)):
  means = list(means_of_slices(a[i],17))
  new_DDD.append(means)
new_DDD = np.array(new_DDD)

print(new_DDD.shape)

final_DDD = []
for i in new_DDD:
  final_DDD.append(np.repeat(i,17))
final_DDD = np.array(final_DDD)

print(final_DDD.shape)
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
(1000, 187, 9)
(1000, 11)
(1000, 187)
```

However I want the output final_DDD to maintain its original shape of DDD_array (1000,187,9) where only the 187 data points are chunked into their means and the third dimension of 9 values stay the same.

The function I have for means_of_slices is:

```
from itertools import islice
def means_of_slices(iterable, slice_size):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        slice = list(islice(iterator, slice_size))
        if slice:
            yield np.sum(slice)/len(slice)
        else:
            return
```

Can you let me know where I am going wrong and how it can be fixed?. Is there a problem in the means function or my loops?

Comment: "However, I want  the output..." -- I found this para somewhat vague. In general it's always best to post your question with minimal sample input data, corresponding expected output data, actual output (or error). You might have to modify the posted code to match the minimal sample input data. "Minimal" here means something much smaller than `(1000, 187, 9)`

Comment: Thanks! will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say:

1. `DDD_array.shape` is `(2,3,2)`.
2. `DDD_array` is

```
[[[ 0,  1],
  [ 2,  3],
  [ 4,  5]],

 [[ 6,  7],
  [ 8,  9],
  [10, 11]]]
```

My understanding is that your expected `final_DDD` is:

```
[[[ 0.5,  0.5],
  [ 2.5,  2.5],
  [ 4.5,  4.5]],

 [[ 6.5,  6.5],
  [ 8.5,  8.5],
  [10.5, 10.5]]]
```

**Solution:**

```
final_DDD = np.broadcast_to(np.mean(DDD_array, axis=-1, keepdims=True), DDD_array.shape)
```

**Note:**
If the expected output is:

```
[[[2., 3.],
  [2., 3.],
  [2., 3.]],

 [[8., 9.],
  [8., 9.],
  [8., 9.]]]
```

then you just need to pass `axis=1` instead of `axis=-1`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will give this a try now.

Comment: Hey! this seems to work but it takes means of all data points and replaces them. if you see my `means_of_slices` function, i want to be able to chunk the means in the number of slices i provide. This means when i give 17 to 187, it takes the mean till every 17th slice, means it and gives back one data point for every 17th slice till 187 (11 in total as 187/17=11). Then repeat each of those 11 data points 17 times to give back 187. How can i specify a particular slice number instead of taking means of all data points?

Comment: I had a good look at ur func `means_of_slices()`. Each value yielded from this generator function corresponds to a slice of data whose shape is `(17,9)`, which is a slice that contains `153` values (since `17*9=153`). For each such slice, `np.sum(slice)` returns the sum of all the `153` values, and then u divide the sum by `17` instead of dividing by `153`. So, the name "mean" is inappropriate and misleading in all this discussion. If this is a proper mean, it would involve summation of X things divided by X, rather than summation of X things divided by Y. Pls confirm whthr this is what u want

Comment: Yes i understand now! thanks a lot for your help and explanation.